# Android Jetpack Compose Preview UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES does not show dark background in preview

Tags: android, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

I am following https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial

and the code

```kotlin
@Preview(name = "Light Mode")
@Preview(name = "Dark Mode", uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED, showBackground = true)
@Preview(name = "Full Preview", showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    ComposeTutorialTheme {
        MessageCard(Message("Roman", "message body"))
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: My team and I have done it manually with a parameter in our base theme which works pretty well for us.

Comment: I've checked the tutorial. They use Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES not Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED like you do. Maybe that's the problem

Comment: It is harder to notice, but that step of the tutorial also adds a `Surface` in the preview (and does not mention it), as a parent for `MessageCard`. Using this technique you can also remove `showBackground = true`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It "works" in the tutorial because they use a `Card` which uses a `Surface` under the hood.

The dark background you are seeing is not produced by the `@Preview` annotation, but rather by the `Surface` which simply draws its own background based on the `MaterialTheme`.

Barebones implementation of `Surface`:

```kotlin
fun Surface(
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier.surface(
            backgroundColor = color
        ),
    ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

`Surface` also overrides the "content color" with

```kotlin
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalContentColor provides contentColorFor(color),
) {
    content()
}
```

so that the text or icons displayed within the `Surface` contrast well with the background color.

---

You still have to set up the `MaterialTheme` to follow the dark theme. Finally, the preview composable would looks something like this:

```kotlin
@Preview
@Preview(uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES)
@Composable
private fun BannerPreview() {
    PlaygroundTheme {
        Surface {
            Banner()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a comparison of how previews like look when you forget to use a `Card`/`Surface` or do not apply an `isSystemInDarkTheme()`-aware `MaterialTheme`:

[image]

Comment: Where is `PlaygroundTheme` defined?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky The `PlaygroundTheme` function just handles light/dark theme and ultimately delegates to `androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme`. It is also generated for you when you create a new Compose project, but its name depends on the name of the project. Where you put this function is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

Another silly reason it might happened even if you added your Theme wrapping Surface wrapping your composable, is that the imports might not be corrected.
since i'm using material3 i need to **use this import**:

```
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
```

Instead of this:

```
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
```

If i'm using the old one (without 3) it is compiling and ignoring ui mode.

Comment: Why do you have both libraries in your project? If you're using material3 you don't need to have the material library there at all. If it's not there it won't be auto imported and `import androidx.compose.material.Surface` would cause a compile error.

Comment: @Niall You are right, it was just between the migrations so I didnt notice that I had them both. thats why I wrote "silly" :)

Answer (score 1):

If you've tried all the tricks and still don't get the preview in dark mode, find the **res/values/themes.xml** file and change the **paren** to **parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight"** (or any other theme, which will affect your preview).

This worked for me and I hope it helps.