# Jetpack Compose Preview background color is different from theme background color

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-preview

I'm just learnig Compose. I want to make Compose Preview background color setting the same as run app mode. What is wrong with my code?

Preview code

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    PreviewTutorialTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        ) {
            Greeting("Android")
        }
    }
}
```

Theme.kt Color code

```
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Purple40,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40,
    tertiary = Pink40,
    background = Color.Red
```

Preview image and Run app image
[image]

I want make Preview theme setting same as run app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72806571/android-jetpack-compose-preview-ui-mode-night-yes-does-not-show-dark-background this one should help you

Comment: Thank you. I solved this problem by changing Theme.kt code "dynamicColor: Boolean = true" to "dynamicColor: Boolean = false"